# MonoTouch.Dialog place two columns side by side

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Most of the examples (maybe all of them) in MonoTouch.Dialog, are for creating iPhone applications, and due to limited screen size, apps are presented as single column, with many elements listed one on top of another.

But in the iPad is a different story, you can actually have two dialogs placed side by side.
Does anyone have a clue on how to achieve that?

(If you dont understand me ...)

```
----------------------------------------------- 

|  StringElement |  |  StringElement |   |    | 

|  StringElement |  |  EntryElement  |   |    | 

|  EntryElement  |  | _______________|   |    |

| ______________ |  |  BooleanElement|   |    |

|                |  |                |   | (0)| --> Home Button

|  StringElement |  |_______________ |   |    |

|  EntryElement  |  |                |   |    |

| _______________|  |                |   |    |

|                |  |                |   |    |

-----------------------------------------------
```

(Horizontally placed iPad)

That took some time to explain.
Thanks for any leads on this

Comment: Do you want 2 dialogs to sit side by side or one dialog that "wraps?"  If you want 2 dialogs you may be able to create a top level root UIViewController that manages 2 sub controllers that are dialogs.

Comment: Any solution that allows me to show two columns, is fine. I think the simpler one would be to put 2 dialogs with one root controller i'll try that

Answer (score 3):

In general it's done with a `UISplitViewController`. You can see a (complete) sample on how to do this (and share code between iPad/iPhone and other platforms) from Xamarin's [MWC2012 sample](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/24/mwc_2012/). The iPad/iPhone versions do use MonoTouch.Dialog.

But there are other approaches that might be a better fit for your application. One I like (since it also works well with iPhones) is the [FlyOutNavigation](https://github.com/Clancey/FlyOutNavigation). The sample code also uses MonoTouch.Dialog.

Comment: I haven´t tried this yet, i'm sorry. But i guess this should be the correct answer. The idea is getting the same layout as the ipad Settings Menu, which consists of one column to select some option and another column to modify the details.